# Handling Views and Foreign keys in Django

Tags: django-views, foreign-keys

I have a simple model in models.py:

```
class Inspection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# сознание#
class Consciousness(models.Model):
    inspection = models.ForeignKey(Inspection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

And I have view.py, where I create context:

```
def Detail(request, inspection_id):
    inspection = get_object_or_404(Inspection, pk=inspection_id)
    consciousness = Consciousness.objects.get(inspection=inspection)
    context = {'inspection':inspection, 'consciousness':consciousness}
    return render(request, 'healthcare/detail.html', context)
```

To use it ine template:

```
<p>{{ inspection.name }}</p>
<p>{{ consciousness.choice_text }}</p>
```

But instead of result, I get:

```
Skin matching query does not exist
```

I guess the problem is in Views.py. I cannot really understand how to between object and object with foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

In fact code is correct. Just object consciousness didn't exist, that's why I got an error. After creation of object, error disappears.
The next point is to handle with Skin matching doesn't exist.
I thank myself for answering the question.